# Tag Cleanup - Ambience / Ambiance / Atmosphere / Background / Background Ambience

Tags: discussion

We currently have five tags on the main site.  [Ambience](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambience), [Ambiance](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambiance), [Atmosphere](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere), [Background](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background) and [Background Ambience](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backgroundambience).  The first two are generally considered synonyms and the rest are very closely related.

There is a bit of a connotation that Ambiance is more of the feeling of a space where as Ambience is more what actually occurs in the space, so there may be room for a distinction, but if we want to have one, we really need to clarify the distinction with a tag wiki and clean up the existing tags.

Does anyone have suggestions for possible Tag Wikis for these tags or is the preference simply to merge them together as the same thing?  If we want to merge them, which one do we want to have survive?  Ambience seems to be the more common usage (both on the site and in general English usage).

If we want to merge the others, I will also set it up as a tag synonym so that it will connect in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I vote you go with "Ambience". The subtle distinction between Ambience and Ambiance is mostly likely unintentional and can be treated as a synonym.